# Particular query causes ADO Recordset to fail with E_FAIL

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado, recordset

i'm trying to run (two) queries against SQL Server 2005 using ADO:

```
SELECT
   sp.nt_username AS NTUsername,
   sp.hostname AS HostName
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks tl
   INNER JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp
   ON tl.request_session_id = sp.spid
WHERE tl.resource_type = N'APPLICATION'
AND tl.resource_database_id = (
       SELECT dbid
       FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
       WHERE spid = @@spid)
```

and the SQL Server 2000 compatible version:

```
SELECT
   sp.nt_username AS NTUsername,
   sp.hostname AS HostName
FROM master.dbo.syslockinfo sli
   INNER JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp
   ON sli.req_spid = sp.spid
WHERE rsc_type = 10 --10=Appliction
AND rsc_dbid = (
   SELECT dbid
   FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
   WHERE spid = @@spid)
```

The query *executes* fine:

```
IRecordset rs =new Recordset();
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient; //the default for a Recordset is adUseServer (Connection.Execute's default is adUseClient)
rs.CursorType := adOpenForwardOnly; //the default
rs.Open(szQuery, conn.ConnectionObject,
       adOpenForwardOnly, //CursorType
       adLockReadOnly, //LockType
       adCmdText);
```

But then ***checking*** the status of `BOF` or `EOF`:

```
if (rs.EOF) then
```

triggers an exception:

- HRESULT: 0x80004005 (Unspecified error)
- Error message: "Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status"

What is about this query that causes ADO to fail so miserably?

---

**Note**: There really ***is*** a matching row:

[image]

The `provider` i'm using in the connection string is `Provider=SQLOLEDB`.

Bonus Chatter:

> ### sysprocesses
>
> ```
>   nt_username nchar(128)
>   hostname    nchar(128)
> ```

and querying for both - but one at a time - works, e.g.:

```
SELECT
   sp.nt_username AS NTUsername
```

and

```
SELECT
   sp.hostname AS HostName
```

work. Querying for both fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem.  [It's a known issue with SQL Server 2005 and ADO](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/75dbff80-2c95-408d-8805-b2fc9cc7a658/):

Even though `nt_username` and `hostname` already *are* `nchar(128)`, you need to **manually** cast them to `nchar(128)`

```
SELECT
   CAST(sp.nt_username AS nchar(128)) AS NTUsername,
   CAST(sp.hostname AS nchar(128)) AS HostName
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks tl
   INNER JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp
   ON tl.request_session_id = sp.spid
WHERE tl.resource_type = N'APPLICATION'
AND tl.resource_database_id = (
       SELECT dbid
       FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
       WHERE spid = @@spid)
```

There is also a known bug with SQL Server 2005 and ADO and the use of `@@spid` in a query; you cannot do it. Fortunately i can, in this case, use `DB_ID()`:

```
SELECT
   CAST(sp.nt_username AS nchar(128)) AS NTUsername,
   CAST(sp.hostname AS nchar(128)) AS HostName
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks tl
   INNER JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses sp
   ON tl.request_session_id = sp.spid
WHERE tl.resource_type = N'APPLICATION'
AND tl.resource_database_id = DB_ID()
```

Bada-bing.

SQL Server 2005 bug.

It might still exist in SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

I know that this problem have several years, but I got the same error and I discovered that the error was related with the connection timeout because the query take more than 30 seconds to execute. I changed 120 seconds and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The "E_FAIL" error message is quite devious, as it can occur at very different circumstances. In my case, a query to create a record set with outer join (left join) and empty result in a field (null) caused this error message.

As found in  [some MS technet forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/msdn-technet-forums/b33ae7a0-f6d1-42a4-80a3-bc549d155820), the used cursor type made the difference:

```
recordSet.CursorLocation = 2 // adUseServer
```

worked, while the formerly used adUseClient = 3 did not.